# Plotting individual dates and types in order on R

Tags: r, date, time, time-series, visualization

I would like to visualize individual dates and types by ID, to identify incorrect ones, such as Start dates that occur after During dates, as per the below example df.

```
dates <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,
                   2,2,3,
                   3,3,4),
            Dates = as.Date(c("2013-12-01","2014-02-02","2014-12-01",
                              "2011-12-31","2012-12-21","2015-11-01",
                              "2016-12-11","2016-12-30","2015-12-07")),
            Type = c("Start", "During", "End",
                     "End", "Start","During",
                    "Start", "End","Start"))
```

I envision something like a set of horizontal lines, each corresponding to an ID. Days with events will be represented with a colored dot, with dots matching the event type - something along the lines of the below, where 'S' is Type start, d is type during, and e is type end.

```
s-----d-----e
d-----s------e
```

Is there a way to do so?

Many thanks, E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve tried something. I guessed you wanted to set out over time? by your --- so maybe this is what you look for.

```
ggplot(dates, aes(Dates, ID, colour = dates$Type))+
geom_point()
```

you can also differentiate start during finish by shape

```
ggplot(dates, aes(Dates, ID, shape = dates$Type))+
geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks that's great